# How do I implement a begin() member function in my custom data structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, iterator, implementation

I'm trying to create my own data-structure that can determine if a value is an element within it in O(1) time with a hash-map.

I'm working on adding more member functions so that it's more similar to the STL containers. Here's what I currently have that's relevant to the problem:

```cpp
template <class T>
class setfind {

private:
    long long _size = 0;
    unordered_map<T, bool> _set;

public:
    // constructors
    setfind() {}
    // initialize from some iterable
    template <class InputIterator>
    setfind(InputIterator beg, InputIterator en){
        _size = en - beg;
        while (beg != en){
            _set[*beg] = true;
            beg++;
        }
    }

    bool contains(const T &val){
        return _set[val];
    }
    bool contains(const T &&val){
        return _set[val];
    }
};
```

As you can see, its core is the unordered_map. I want to write a member function that returns a begin iterator to the _set variable. I tried putting this in:

```cpp
template <class InputIterator>
InputIterator begin()
{
    return _set.begin();
}
```

but that led to a compilation error saying that there was no matching member function.
I don't know enough about iterators and template-classes to fix this. Does anyone know how to implement it or what's wrong? Are there any good resources so that I can learn more about this?

Also some optimization tips for this class would be appreciated because this is going to be used under a time-limit.

EDIT: I’m restricted to using c++11 
EDIT2: Fixed a bug in the constructor 
EDIT3: Memory leaks and best-practices will not be an issue

Comment: Why not just use an `unordered_set`?

Comment: @Kevin because as far as I’ve researched it has worst-case O(n) and I want to guarantee that it’s O(1)

Comment: `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` have essentially identical complexity: O(1) expected, but O(n) worst case for both.

Comment: In most standard library implementations, `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` are built on top of the same hashtable internals. By the standard, they're required to do linked lists from each point in the table. The big difference is that map stores `std::pair<const Key, Value>` and does equality and hash calculations on just the key, while set just stores values and directly compares them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues with your code.

You don't need the `_size` member at all, get rid of it and use `_set.size()` when needed.

In your constructor, `while (*beg != *en)` needs to be `while (beg != en)` instead.  Or better, just geet rid of the manual loop altogether and use the `std::unordered_map` constructor that takes an iterator pair as input:

```cpp
// initialize from some iterable
template <class InputIterator>
setfind(InputIterator beg, InputIterator en) : _set(beg, en) {}
```

In your `contains()` methods, use `_set.find()` or `_set.contains()` instead of `_set.operator[]` to avoid `val` begin added to the `_set` if it does not already exist.  Also, it does not make sense to take a `const` rvalue reference, so just get rid of that overload altogether:

```cpp
bool contains(const T &val) const
{
    return _set.find(val) != _set.end();
    // or:
    // return _set.contains(val);
}
```

And lastly, for your `begin()` method, just use `auto` for the return type instead of a template, let the compiler deduce the necessary type, eg:

```cpp
auto begin()
{
    return _set.begin();
}
```

**UPDATE**: apparent `auto` return type deduction was introduced in C++14.  So, for C++11, you will just have to state the type explicitly, still don't use a template for it, eg:

```cpp
unordered_map<T, bool>::iterator begin()
{
    return _set.begin();
}
```

Or:

```cpp
auto begin() -> unordered_map<T, bool>::iterator
{
    return _set.begin();
}
```

Or:

```cpp
auto begin() -> decltype(_set.begin())
{
    return _set.begin();
}
```

You can simplify this by declaring an `iterator` alias in your class (which you should do anyway, if your goal is to make your class act like a standard container), eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
class setfind {
private:
    unordered_map<T, bool> _set;

public:
    using iterator = unordered_map<T, bool>::iterator;

    ...

    iterator begin(){
        return _set.begin();
    }
};
```

Comment: Since I'm limited to c++11, I don't have access to the _set.contains method or return value deduction

Comment: @feverdream "*I don't have access to the _set.contains method*" - that is why I also suggested `_set.find()`. "*or return value deduction*" - then you are going to have to specify the type explicitly, not with a template. I have updated my answer to show that.

Comment: a quick question: why *does* the documentation say that unordered_map::find is best case O(1) and worst case O(n)? Shouldn't it always be O(1) since you just need to hash the value or am I being really dumb here

Comment: @feverdream you are assuming the implementation of the search uses hashes. It is not required to, but that would be ideal. But it *can* use a linear search instead, if it wants to.